# IntelliJ Idea: how add more shortcuts tips on the first screen?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Is there a way to add more shortcuts tips on the first screen (when you not open any file yet)? I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3.

The image showing the default shortcuts:

[image]

I would like to add more shortcuts, because it's hard to remember some shortcuts and it will be nice use this screen to help on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK this screen is fixed and cannot be customized. If you are curious about shortcuts there are several helpful ways:

1. Enable `Tip of the day`. Go to `Help->Tip of the day` and mark checkbox `Show tips on startup`
2. Install official [IntelliJ Features trainer](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/12/ide-features-trainer/). You can learn IntelliJ shortcuts for the most used IDE actions.
3. Install Key promoter plugin. It will show you hotkey which you could use for every 'mouse' action you perform. This will definetely help you to learn hotkeys for actions which you really use.

   [image: Key promoter plugin]
4. open `Help -> Keymap reference`, print out the file and hang it on the wall next to your workplace (Thanks to Andrew)

Comment: 4. open `Help` -> `Keymap reference`, print out the file and hang it on the wall next to your workplace

Comment: Thanks @AndrewTobilko, I've added it to answer.

Answer (score 3):

Not too sure how that can be customised. But you could use <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and then type the action you are looking to perform. This should show the shortcut associated with the action you are looking to perform and also execute the action.